# Div with rounded border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't understand the formula to obtain a larger rounded bottom border of my div, and if there is a easier way to implement it within Bootstrap.

This is how it is now:

[image: how it is now]

And how I would like to develop it:

[image]

```css
.header {
background-color: blue;
height: 40px;
width: 90px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 180px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 180px;
border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your goal image is using css and border radius? I have a feeling it is probably a background image.

Comment: Absolutely it could, the border radius was just an assumption...first time I need to implement a border in that way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `border-radius` and some **overflow**, so you may rely on a pseudo-element.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.header:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:-10px;
  right:-10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
```

Or use `radial-gradient`:

```css
.header-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top, blue 50%, transparent 51%) center/200% 250% no-repeat;
}

.header-2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, blue 50%, transparent 53%) 50% 100%/170% 150% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-1">

</div>

<div class="header-2">

</div>
```

Or also `clip-path`:

```css
.header {
  height: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
-webkit-clip-path: ellipse(60% 50% at 50% 50%);
clip-path: ellipse(60% 50% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution that works good for me

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:2;
}
.header{
  height:60px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:-20px;
  right:-20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
  padding:10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 15px 10px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    this is the header
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of *clip-path* we can get this output

```css
.first-div{
background:#007dbf;
height:400px;
clip-path: ellipse(70% 49% at 50% 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div"></div>
```